# How to get past the exception no printer found? - rdlc

Tags: c#, wpf, rdlc

I am developing a wpf app with Microsoft report viewer. Everything worked fine, but when I went to my client to show him how the reports look like, I connected via remote desktop to my PC and showed him.After that, when I came back from my client and tried to change something, I get an exception where it says that no printer is found. The problem is with the page settings.

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pg = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
pg.Margins.Top = 0;
pg.Margins.Bottom = 0;
pg.Margins.Left = 0;
pg.Margins.Right = 0;

reportViewerObrazac02.SetPageSettings(pg);
```

At my PC I do not have a printer. I know that is the problem,but how can I get past that? When I used my app over remote, I got the printer settings of my client. How can I remove that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,it's simple.
You just go to your Devices and Printers(Start-Printers) and there under printers and faxes you select something as a default printer.For me it was Microsoft XPS Document Writter.
After that,in your app rdlc let's you use everything for testing like you need.